# UINavigationcontroller initWithRootViewController from appDelegate, empty view?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I ran into a problem.

I want to initialize an UINavigationcontroller with an UIViewController. As my Viewcontroller gets loaded from a .xib I am using

```
UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appDelegate.myViewController];
```

[self presentModalViewController:myNavigationController animated:YES];

Unfortunately my view is empty.

Am I doing something wrong or is there an other way achieving my aim?

If I am allocating an instance of my Viewcontroller like so

```
UIViewController *aController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

And having a button inside the nib, my app crashes when tapping on it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

myViewController *aController = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

or

UIViewController *aController = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

then push it

since

if u type like this

UIViewController *aController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

u allocating UIViewController and doesn't know about ur button in default UIViewcontroller

which means does n't have UIButton property.

so it crashes